# How to update a state when other states get updated?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I am using React, and have a state, 'modifiedState', which should be set to 'true' when any of several other states get modified, and then 'false' elsewhere in my code.

I am currently trying to use the useEffect function to achieve this, but it doesn't appear to be modifying. My code looks like,

```
const myApp = () => {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState();
    const [state2, setState2] = useState();
    const [state3, setState3] = useState();
    const [state4, setState4] = useState();

    const [isModified, setIsModified] = useState(false);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log("useEffect triggered");
            setIsModified(true);
        },
        [state1, state2, state3, state4]
    )
    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log("We set isModified to", isModified);
        },
        [isModified]
    )
```

Unfortunately, based on what I read, this won't work, because you're not supposed to use setState inside of useEffect. Is there a different way I can change a state in response to other states being updated?

Comment: "this won't work" yes it will. It's fine to call setState inside useEffect.

Comment: It's an anti pattern to create a state based on another state, but it will work